# HOw to show the tooltip for an image in the jqGrid?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, tooltip

HOw to show the tooltip for an image in the jqGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check this >>> [Custom Data ToolTips for jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201473/custom-data-tooltips-in-jqgrid-3-4)

Answer (score 0):

you can use qtip plugin of jquery for this. in my case i have to show tool tip when particular jqgrid cell get focused.

```
LoadToolTipRackId = function (elem) {

    jQuery(elem).qtip({
        content: 'this is an image',
        show: 'focusin',
        hide: 'focusout',
        style:
    {

        name: 'red',
        tip: 'leftBottom',
        textAlign: 'left',
        fontWeight: '500',
        fontSize: '11px'

    },
        position:
    {
        corner:
        {
            target: 'rightMiddle',
            tooltip: 'leftBottom'
        }
    }
    });
}
```

you can visit following link to find out more about qtip plugin
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

whereas i have to set following column properties in jqgrid in colmodel

```
editoptions: { size: 7, defaultValue: '0.00000', maxlength: 15, dataInit: LoadToolTipRackId}
```